# Find the limit of $f(x)$ involving a sum of logarithms.

Tags: functions, limits, logarithms

I need to find

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)$ for the following function:

$f:(0,+\infty)$

$f(x)=[1+\ln(1+x)+\ln(1+2x)+\dots+\ln(1+nx)]^\frac{1}{x}$

I tried writing the logarithms as products:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}[1+\ln(1+x)(1+2x)\dots(1+nx)]^\frac{1}{x}$

and as a sum and nothing is getting me anywhere.

Also I know I have to use the formula: 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}=e$

Can someone please help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You want $\lim_{x\to0}$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty}$?

Comment: I need $lim_{x\rightarrow0}$. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @GrozavAlexIoan $\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$, $x\to0$.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately $e$ is not one of the possible answers.

Comment: @Andrew's hint works all right (and does not yield the limit e).

Comment: Which means the limit is equal to 1?

Comment: ?? There are other numbers than 1 and e in this world, yaknow... By the way, did you try anything at all yourself, or are you waiting for a full solution to appear on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, take $\ln$ to both sides, gives,

$$\ln  \left( f \left( x \right)  \right) ={\frac {\ln  \left( 1+\sum _{
k=1}^{n}\ln  \left( 1+kx \right)  \right) }{x}}
 $$

Using Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+t)= t+ O(t) $ at the point $t=0$ with $t =  {\sum _{k=1}^{n}\ln \left( 1+kx \right) } $  yields

$$ \ln  \left( f \left( x \right)  \right) ={\frac {\sum _{k=1}^{n}\ln 
 \left( 1+kx \right) }{x}} + \frac{O\left(\left( {\sum _{k=1}^{n}\ln 
 \left( 1+kx \right) } \right)^2\right)}{x} $$

Taking the limit as x goes to $0$ to both sides of the above equation gives

$$ \lim_{x->0}\ln(f(x))=\ln(\lim_{x->0} f(x) ) =\sum _{k=1}^{n}{k}^{} =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\,.$$

Exponentiating the last result, we get the answer

$$ {\rm e}^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} $$

Comment: There is an error. Check the link between the second equation and the third: in the third, no inverses should appear, so the limit is much simpler.

Comment: If $x$ yields $0$ wouldn't the result be $ln(f(x))=\sum^n_{k=1}0+O(\sum^n_{k=1}0)$ meaning $f(x)=e^0$ => $\lim f(x)=1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

(Edited in response to comment)

$$\log f={\log\bigl(1+\log(1+x)+\log(1+2x)+\cdots+\log(1+nx)\bigr)\over x}$$ By l'Hopital, the limit, if it exists, is the same as the limit of $${\left({1\over1+x}+{2\over1+2x}+\dots+{n\over1+nx}\right)\over\left(1+\log(1+x)+\log(1+2x)+\cdots+\log(1+nx)\right)}$$ But now you can just set $x$ equal to zero.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did at the first part (how the $\frac{log}{x}$ appeared) and how you got the $(\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{2}{1+2x}+\dots+\frac{n}{1+nx})$? Thank you very much!

Comment: I took the log on both sides - are you familiar with $\log a^b=b\log a$? Are you familiar with l'Hopital? Do you know that the derivative of $\log(1+kx)$ is $k/(1+kx)?

Comment: I'm familiar with the logarithm properties and l'Hopital. I didn't know the derivative of $log(1+kx)$ though. This means the answer is $e^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$m right?

Comment: Note that the term in my answer that comes out to $n(n+1)/2$ is in the denominator.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why is that term in the denominator?  Isn't that term essentially your du, where u is equal to that sum with all the logs?

Comment: @Mike, you're right, I'll edit.